# The matplotlib pie chart graph shows a strange picture

Tags: python, matplotlib

my code is here

```
def diagnosisGraph():
    indexD, Dpage, D, Dlevel = depressiondiagnosis.depression()
    indexA, Apage, A, Alevel = drugaddiction.addiction()

    page_data = [indexD - Dpage - Apage, Dpage, Apage]
    page_categories = ['normal', 'depression', 'drug-addiction']
    plt.pie(page_data,
            labels=page_categories,
            colors=['mediumseagreen', 'lightgrey', 'salmon'],
            autopct='%.2f',
            )
    plt.legend(page_categories)

    plt.savefig('static/diagnosisGraph.png')
```

When I draw a pie chart graph, a strange shape comes out

[image]

how can I do

Comment: Try adding the axis method, and see if that works. plt.axis('equal')

Comment: Oh plt.axis('scaled') worked!! thank you

Comment: great. Do you mind if I put it as the answer?

Comment: I thought it worked, but when I tried it again, I got wrong results. So I tried putting plt.axis ('equal') back and it worked fine. But on the second try again, it gives weird results. This seems like an incomplete answer.

Comment: Im thinking there may be something else at play here. Do you have some sample data that can be shared to try and recreate?

Answer (score 0):

the plt.axis() method will give you what is needed.

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html